# Change permissions on the Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script (Script by spreadsheet) who writes a series of data in a spreadsheet, but some parts of the spreadsheet are locked.

The users that are running this script from the spreadsheet are blocked in certain areas, it is possible that Script release these areas and then lock them again or run as adm of the Spreadsheet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user would need to have permission to edit sharing on the Spreadsheet, which would not be the case if it was locked.

Is the script an `onEdit` trigger? If so, you can add a trigger from the script editor that will run as yourself. Just make sure to rename `onEdit()` to something else so it doesn't try to run as the regular user as well.

If this isn't onEdit, I would suggest making the function they call add a specific value to a specific cell. Then you can have a timed trigger every minute running as yourself that watches this cell and does its work when the cell contains the specific word. Just make sure to clear the cell quickly so it doesn't run twice.